# how to select a some characters from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have a url strings like 
"example.com/Apps/Visitor/visitscanner" ,
"example.com/Apps/Seatings/visitscanner

i want to select the directory name after the ""http://example.com/Apps/"

for above example url's, if my url string is "http://example.com/Apps/Visitor/visitscanner" this one, then results should be like "Visitor".

How can i do this in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), like:

```
var str = "example.com/Apps/Visitor/visitscanner";
var parts = str.split('/');
console.log( parts[parts.length - 2] ); //Visitor
```

Comment: Suggestion, try reading docs before you get into coding that would help a lot.. !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regex if you want to match URLs like `"http://example.com/Apps/Visitor/visitscanner/foo"` or `"http://example.com/Apps/Visitor"`...

```
var url = "http://example.com/Apps/Visitor/visitscanner";
var match = /^(https?:\/\/)?example.com\/apps\/([^/]+)/i.exec(url);
var directory = match[2]; // get the second match group ("Visitor")
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ra6S5/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a regex like :-

```
var url = "http://example.com/Apps/Visitor/visitscanner";
var dirName  = /\/\/.+?\/Apps\/(.+?)(?=\/)/g.exec(url)[1];
```